# Auto updating records in controller Angular meteor

Tags: javascript, angularjs, mongodb, meteor, angular-meteor

I am using angular in my meteor app and i am looking at this behavior when the record in a controller variable is automatically updated  on the client whenever there is a change in that record on the server or if you change it from the db itself. Below is my code

**Client.js**

```
(function() {
    angular.module('testApp')
        .controller('TestController', TestController);

    //inject dependencies required    
    TestController.$inject = ['$state', '$mdDialog', '$reactive', '$scope'];

    function TestController($state, $mdDialog, $reactive, $scope) {
        var vm = this;
        vm.dineInArray = [];

        // to attach the scope to reactive var
        $reactive(vm).attach($scope);

        vm.helpers({
            tables: function() {
                return Tables.find({});
            }            
        });

        var tableOrderCompSubscription = vm.subscribe('tableOrders');

        Tracker.autorun(function() {
            if (tableOrderCompSubscription.ready()) {
                createDineInArray();
            }
        });

        function createDineInArray() {
            var tempArray = [];
            var order;
            vm.tables.forEach(function(table) {
                order = Orders.findOne({ tableId: table._id });
                if (order) {
                    table.orderId = order._id;
                    table.menuItems = order.menuItems;
                }
                tempArray.push(table);
            });            
            vm.dineInArray = tempArray;
        }
    }
})();
```

**Server.js**

```
Meteor.publishComposite('tableOrders', {
        find: function() {
            // Find top ten highest scoring posts
            return Tables.find({});
        },
        children: [{
            find: function(table) {
                // Find post author. Even though we only want to return
                // one record here, we use "find" instead of "findOne"
                // since this function should return a cursor.
                return Orders.find({ tableId: table._id }, { limit: 1 });
            }
        }]
    });
```

Now in the above code i am publishing a mixed object which is made up of two collections with the help of [this](https://github.com/englue/meteor-publish-composite/) meteor package. I get the data that is published via `tableOrders` collection in `Tables` and `Orders` collection on the client which is perfect. I do some processing on the data and then add all data to vm.dineInArray variable of controller inside the `createDineInArray()` function which is called when the subscription is ready. Below is my html that uses `vm.dineInArray`

**HTML**

```
<div flex layout="row" ng-controller="TestLayoutController as vm">
    <!--Title bar end-->
    <div layout="row" flex>
        <md-content flex layout="row" layout-wrap>
            <md-card class="table-card" md-ink-ripple ng-repeat="item in vm.dineInArray">
                <div flex layout="row" class="table-card-body" layout-align="center center">
                    <p>{{item.pending}} / {{item.quantity}}</p>
                </div>
                <div layout="row" class="table-card-footer" layout-align="center center">
                    <h4>{{ item.name }}</h4>
                </div>
            </md-card>
        </md-content>
    </div>
</div>
```

Now suppose i have 1 record in `Tables` collection and hence i get 1 item in `dineInArray` that is rendered on my view. What happens is when i change the values in that record directly from mongo db via some GUI tool as Robomongo and update it, that corresponding record inside the dineInArray is automatically updated without me doing anything.

I know that if the helper function gets called every time something changes but the function that generates my array is not being called from helpers. I am calling it when Tracker indicates that subscription is ready and hence i can't figure out how does the record in my array update itself with its latest value from Server.

I may be missing something obvious but i want to know the reason this occurs and how can i benefit/damage from it

Any help ?

Comment: It's doing what Meteor is designed to do, out of the box. Any updates to the database are reflected immediately in the gui. This is in the design of Meteor in the core.

Comment: The thing is that i am using a custom function that process my data before binding it to the model which the gui uses. Unless the function is called when database is updated how come the GUI gets the new data ?

Comment: Please read the Meteor documentation. Collection.find() returns a cursor. Cursors are a reactive data source. On the client, the first time you retrieve a cursor's documents with fetch, map, or forEach inside a reactive computation (eg, a template or autorun), Meteor will register a dependency on the underlying data. Any change to the collection that changes the documents in a cursor will trigger a recomputation. To disable this behavior, pass {reactive: false} as an option to find.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Yes that dependency is the cause for auto updating of my custom array. It doesn't matter how you create your data or if you do it in a separate function, as long as you pull data directly from meteor's collection anywhere in your code, it will be updated when its changed in db.

You can post an separate comment and i will mark it as an answer.

Comment: Thanks Vinay. I have posted an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the Meteor documentation, which explains the process in detail.

Collection.find() returns a cursor.

> Cursors are a reactive data source. On the client, the first time you
>   retrieve a cursor's documents with fetch, map, or forEach inside a
>   reactive computation (eg, a template or autorun), Meteor will register
>   a dependency on the underlying data. Any change to the collection that
>   changes the documents in a cursor will trigger a recomputation. To
>   disable this behavior, pass {reactive: false} as an option to find.

**Added Tip for your angular controller** : It doesn't matter how you create your data or if you do it in a separate function, as long as you pull data directly from meteor's collection anywhere in your code, it will be updated when its changed in db.